# Checking a table is empty in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. I am creating a blog where people can post and comment. If there are no comments to a particular post, how can I show the message "no comments"? I tried

```
@post.comments.any? ? 'no comments' : ''
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Run that query on your console and show us the response you get. At first seems fine. Or show us a snippet of your code where this is being implemented

Comment: `not working` -- So.... What happens?

Comment: Please show the code where this is being implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used your comment in a wrong place. You can try this:

```
@post.comments.any? ? '' : 'no comments'
```

Comment: how can i print the no:of comments in the above statement?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Doesn't it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.blank?` function so in your case it should be something like: `<% if @post.comments.blank? do %> <p>No comments</p>else...`

Comment: Not necessarily. The `#any?` is absolutely valid

Comment: <p>
  <% if @post.comments.blank? do %> <p>No comments</p>
  <b>Commenter:</b>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p> still not working.